# Obtaining the Flux-Time plot for a Quasar

Tags: observational-astronomy, quasars, light-curve

As a follow up question to [Obtaining the Light curve of a a Quasar](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47018/7982), I wish to know how to obtain a Light curve for a quasar observation like [this *data set* over here](http://faculty.washington.edu/ivezic/REU08/quasarweb/variability/4950833.dat).

Is there an archival repository where I can find processed csvs of quasar observations like these for a testing of a particular theory that i need to carry out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I am okay with handling FITS file on Python so it might be helpful in that aspect.

Comment: I believe this comment is more of an answer to my question above.

Comment: Try going to MAST, find some random quasar (or a popular one/ famous one to increase your odds of finding data) and you might be able to find the processed .fits images and can make a light curve yourself using some popular variable star software (my go to is AstroImageJ, but it’s optimized for transiting planets; photometry is photometry though), or if you don’t have the means to do that, you could always look on arXiv for a paper about a quasar that you find data for; they would probably have some paper that made a light curve. Here’s the link for MAST: https://archive.stsci.edu/

Comment: You could in theory remove the count data alone from the fits files and put it in a csv file using IRAF as well, if you’d like those files in a file like rhat

Comment: Thanks a ton! I shall try those and update here :)

Comment: I just used Pandas to make a data frame and used the Lightkurve package on Python to plot them and analyse further. Currently, I am trying to fit curves on the light curve to obtain the frequency etc.

Comment: @mnuizhre I see that you've spent your hard-earned first reputation points on a bounty and that's great! If you are also interested in receiving answer here, I can add a bounty to this one as well. I'm a pretty active "bountier". On the other hand, if you think you've solved this now it's always okay to answer your own question, even if you think the solution is incomplete. That way other users can see better what's still needed and perhaps add another answer.

Comment: @uhoh Yeah I am pretty stuck on that question and I earn reputation points so I can spend them! Thanks for the info and help offer, but, I have solved this question and I shall update with an answer that I got.

Comment: @mnuizhre oh, that's great! Okay thanks and congrats

Answer (score 1):

So I found the [MAST archival repository](https://mast.stsci.edu/portal/Mashup/Clients/Mast/Portal.html) to be very helpful to obtain the processed FITS file for the object of my interest.

We can enter the object's name (if it's a popular object) or the galactic coordinates to find the area around and the object. I got the quasar data from Kepler's second mission data from the same repository mentioned before.